# What types of back end functionality exist for APIs?

Tags: web-services, architecture, backend

Let's say there is a front end client that talks to a back end with its own data store. The back end returns some payload data that the front end uses to render the page. Here are the 'types' of behavior I can think for the back end and my questions are:

How does one go and decide which implementation to go with?
What are the conventions for back end behavior?

Implementations I can think of:

1. The back end schedules jobs to fetch data from an external API, processes important information, and stores it to its own data store. When front end fetches for this data, back end returns what it fetches from its own data store.
2. Whenever the front end requests for data, the back end service calls external API, processes important information, and returns it to front end. No data store is involved. A followup to this is what is the benefit of doing this in the back end opposed to just calling the external API in the front end?

Are there other types of implementations that I haven't accounted for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about a standard [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) pattern.  The downside is almost always around cache expiration.  How long is the local data good for?  Is it always valid?  How do you detect changes?  Do you do write-through or write-behind?

If these are not concerns, then you have an easy answer, do lots of caching.

Comment: Yes it can be seen as caching i guess. It's more of an update to the data store. If you need to calculate numbers based off multiple external API data, you wouldn't want to call all of them every time a front end client requests for it. You would occasionally calculate this with a scheduled task to keep the data up to date.